# Preloader not running

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop

Iam trying to run preloader with percentage but it not show the percent in dynamic text please anyone give the solution..

```
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;

loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loading);

  function loading(e:ProgressEvent):void
  {
    var Percent:Number = e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal*100;
    myText.text = Math.round(Percent)+"%";



if(Percent == 100)
{
    loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loading);


}
 }
```

Comment: Try to replace `myText.text = Math.round(Percent)+"%";` with `trace(Math.round(Percent)+"%");`. Do you see 100% in Output panel?

Comment: (1) Answer above comment since above shown code is not enough for us to test your issue (2) Declare `var Percent:Number = 0;` outside of and before any functions. Then you update the var as `Percent = e.bytesLo... etc` (3) Make sure font is embedded for your text field